# Apple Account Verification

Tags: security, apple-id

Last week I attempted to log into my apple@me.com account and it stated that my account needed verification and is locked.  To verify, I can have an e-mail sent or answer security questions.  The address that the e-mail is being sent to is the very account that I am locked out of.  There are 3 security questions, of which I need two correct.  I only have one correct (it won't tell me which one) and I've exhausted all possible options.  Apple support is telling me that my only option is to figure out the security questions.  Why I appreciate the security, this is an account used for gaming and I refuse to believe that there is no other way I can verify my identity.  I have other accounts linked to this one and they are telling me that that doesn't matter either.  Any options or specific contacts I can reach out to would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First, check and see if you can log in to your account at [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com). Support can help you a lot more if you can log in here, since you can get a support PIN (which acts as a password). 

Tell them your support PIN (found at the very bottom of the page) and they will know that it's you and can fix your account with only one security question.

---

Your Apple ID should also be set up with a non-apple email address, and that should be where you are getting your codes. Check all of you emails, spam folders and all, to make sure you didn't miss an account reset email. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Bear with me - it can get hard to follow.

So the original Apple '@me.com' email addresses were created back when 'MobileMe' was still a thing. You didn't need a 3rd party email address to acquire an '@me.com' email address from Apple like you do now for '@icloud.com' email accounts. A few years ago, Apple transitioned from 'MobileMe' to 'iCloud'. It was a forced transition as after a few months they flipped the switch on the 'MobileMe' servers and you could no longer access the account (or the data stored within the account) unless you followed the migration procedure in the email that they sent you multiple times.

One step of this forced-transition was that they requested that you bind a 3rd party email address to your account as either an alternate login or a rescue address (likely for situations such as these), but you may not in fact remember doing it even if you had. If you did follow through with this step though, there may be good news ahead!

Note: I cannot guarantee that this will work not knowing what details you chose to provide iCloud *years* ago, but it's worth a shot.

**My suggestion**: Go to [iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid) and click the blue link that says 'Forgot Apple ID?' It should take you to a screen where it requests your first name, last name, and an email address. Type the 3rd party email address (like hotmail, gmail, outlook, etc) that you would have most likely used let's say, 3-4 years ago. Upon continuing, if it tells you "No Apple ID Found. We can’t find an Apple ID matching the information provided." click 'Try Again'. Continue to enter all of the email addresses you owned as far back as you can remember that even had a slight chance of you using them. If after entering all email addresses you can remember it still has not found one that matches your information, I apologize but my suggestion did not work.

If one of the email addresses you provided finds an Apple ID, return to [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin) and attempt to log in with it using the same password you would use to log in with your '@me.com' account.

Upon logging in:

- If it tells you that your password is incorrect, it's actually a
  second separate account that you created at some point
- If it lets you log in without telling you that your account is locked
  and needs verification, it's actually a second
  separate account that you created at some point (and just happened to
  use the same password); this is not helpful in recovering your main account
- If it lets you log in and gives you the same message that your
  account is locked and needs verification, and the security questions appear to be the same, this is *very likely* the same account, and this email address should have also been sent the password reset email (I'm hoping that if you got this far, that you still have access to this email account, otherwise all of this will not have not been helpful)

One last thing to note is, if you ever set up something called a 'Rescue Email Address' this bypasses all other email addresses you associated with the account and the Reset Password email will **only** be sent to that address.